# How to Import Spring Boot (Maven project) war file in Eclipse for edit files

Tags: spring-boot, eclipse, import, war, maven-plugin

I have Spring Boot war file (Maven project). I want to import war file in Eclipse but it only open packages but no Java files are loaded but I want to edit those files.

I tried to import as web (war file), by using this method only packages are created but no Java files are loaded. Only empty packages are there.

Note : I'm using Eclipse 2022-03 version and I try with latest version too but issue not resolved.

Comment: Generally, a war file is the result of the compilation and packaging of the source code of the project, and doesn't contain the actual source code (except some resources such as jsp files if they're used). If you don't have the source code that was used to produce that war file, you won't be able to edit the Java files.

Answer (score 0):

as @Bruno have mentioned, files are already compiled (to .class files), so you can't just import them and start editing.

but you can use something like winrar to unzip the war then use java decompiler like [this one](https://java-decompiler.github.io/) (I actually don't know if it's a good one "it's the first thing that popped in google") to decompile the files.

NOTE: the decompilation is never perfect but it's the best you can do

Answer (score 0):

You can import either WAR file or Maven project. They have a different folder structures.

In Eclipse it'called **Import WAR Archive**. It's well described [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/rsar/9.5?topic=projects-importing-web-archive-war-files).

> A Web Archive (WAR) file is a portable, packaged Web application that you can import into your workspace.
>
> Before importing a WAR file, you should first determine if the WAR file contains needed Java™ source files. When importing a WAR file into an existing Web project, the imported Web deployment descriptor files are either not changed or overwritten by the ones included in the imported WAR file, based on your response to the prompt that is provided. In either case, this action does not represent a merging of the two sets of deployment descriptors.
>
> To import the Web project resources in a WAR file into your workspace, complete the following steps:
>
> 1. Select **File > Import** .
> 2. In the **Import** dialog, select WAR file and then click **Next**.
> 3. Locate the WAR file that you want to import using the **Browse** button.
> 4. The wizard assumes you want to create a *new* Web project with the same name as the WAR file. If you accept this choice, the project will be created with the same servlet version as specified by the WAR file and in the same location. If you want to override these settings, you can click **New** and specify your new settings in the Dynamic Web Project wizard.
> 5. Click **Finish** to populate the Web project.

---

If you want to import Maven project to Eclipse then you can read [here](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-import-eclipse).

---

In other way you should create a new web project from the existing war file. There should be an option in menu or dialog.

Also, you should know that source code can be packaged in war file in `WEB-INF/src`, but it is optional. They are not needed to deploy and run a war file.

If you have source code files packaged separately, then you can extract them and copy to the new project `src` folder or repackage a war file to add required source files before the new project is created. The war file is packaged in the ZIP archiver format, so it can be managed with any archiver utility that support this format.

---

Probably you should know a [Maven project structure](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) and installed Eclipse Maven Plugin. How to work with Maven project in Eclipse you can read [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/maven-eclipse-ide).